# When c++ instantiating method?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang

I am trying to compile this code with gcc and clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template<int N>
struct Test
{
    template<typename = std::enable_if_t<N == 1, bool>>
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "Test::func" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<0> t;

    //t.func();
}
```

So, I have an error:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, bool>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to 
disable this declaration
template <bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Bp, _Tp>::type;
```

But if I compile that code with vc++ there is no error.
**So, which compiler resolves this issue according to c++ standard?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC and Clang are correct here.

When you write `Test<0>` that will substitute `N` with 0. In the declaration of `func` the `std::enable_if_t` will try to access the member `::type` which does not exist. That's an error because that member does not exist and you cannot have a declaration as such.

The way that SFINAE works is that, **during overload resolution**, when the compiler performs template argument deduction, if the substitution of an argument in the template fails, you don't get an error and the function is discarded from the potential overload set. On your example, there is no template argument deduction. N is already known from the class template and because of that the declaration of `func` is ill-formed before overload resolution even begins.

A potential workaround for your use case is this:

```
template<int M = N, typename = std::enable_if_t<M == 1, bool>>
void func()
{
    std::cout << "Test::func" << std::endl;
}
```

That way, `func` now depends on a function template argument, `M`, and SFINAE works as expected.

Comment: Hm... I thought, if I do not use function `func`, then compiler do not instantiates and generate code for that function. **"Note that code is instantiated only for template (member) functions that are called.
For class templates, member functions are instantiated only if they are used."** - this is quotation from C++ Templates The Complete Guide 2nd edition.

Comment: It is true that the template will not be instantiated, but it still needs to be a valid function template declaration. In this case it will not be, the declaration is ill-formed. You can have invalid code in the *body* of a template function that is not called, but not on its declaration (unless SFINAE applies, and in this case it does not because there is no substitution).